# How do I include this directory in the $PATH env var?

Tags: node.js, path, environment-variables

I'm building a package for [Github's Atom](https://atom.io/) editor and Im running into a challenge trying to get a child process to execute with node js. I'm pretty sure that the problem is that the environment that Atom runs in, doesn't include the path to the mrt script. So when I run this from within my package:

```
exec = require("child_process").exec
child = undefined
child = exec("/usr/local/bin/mrt add iron-router", { cwd: path },(error, stdout, stderr) -
  console.log "stdout: " + stdout
  console.log "stderr: " + stderr
  console.log "exec error: " + error  if error isnt null
  return
)
```

in the console, I get:

[image]

Atom has a web inspector built right into it and you can actually see the Paths that atom has included. So when I go to Atom's console and type: `process.env.PATH` it shows the paths: `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`. So I somehow need to make atom aware of that mrt script's path. Anyone know how I might go about doing that?

I also reached out on on [Atom's discussion forum](http://discuss.atom.io/t/how-to-execute-node-js-child-process-from-package/4880) yesterday, but have yet to come up with a solution.

#### Edit:

I should also note that the normal command for excuting the mrt package installer is `mrt add package-name` but as advised on [Atom's discussion forum](http://discuss.atom.io/t/how-to-execute-node-js-child-process-from-package/4880), I've been using the full path.

#### Edit 2:

I've creating symlinks to node in my `/usr/bin` directory, and it's working now. Now I'm trying to get node to create the symlinks for me using fs.symlink but that doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: try executing `which mrt` what results do you get?

Comment: @Phoenix I got: `/usr/local/bin/mrt`

Answer (score 1):

To sum it up, the problem is that Atom uses PATH from where it is launched. Consequently, the path to node and the path to mrt where not included in Atom's path. The solution came to me when someone on the Atom Discussion forum pointed out Atom's [Class BufferedNodeProcess](https://atom.io/docs/api/v0.73.0/api/).
At the time of Answer there is a slight bug with that class so I was not able to use it - the Github team works fast, I wouldn't be surprised if it was fixed within the next couple days. I was, however, able use some of the code to get Atom's environments. Also, I ended up using [node's spawn method](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) instead of execute since that's what BufferedNodeProcess uses. Plus you can read each individual line of the stdout.

```
options =
  cwd: atom.project.getPath()

options.env = Object.create(process.env)  unless options.env?

options.env["ATOM_SHELL_INTERNAL_RUN_AS_NODE"] = 1
node = (if process.platform is "darwin" then path.resolve(process.resourcesPath, "..", "Frameworks", "Atom Helper.app", "Contents", "MacOS", "Atom Helper") else process.execPath)

mrt = spawn(node, [
  "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/bin/mrt.js"
  "add"
  "iron-router"
], options )

mrt.stdout.on "data", (data) ->
  console.log "stdout: " + data
  return

mrt.stderr.on "data", (data) ->
  console.log "stderr: " + data
  return

mrt.on "close", (code) ->
  console.log "child process exited with code " + code
  return
```